# mongoose update nested document using date ranged failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to update a set of array of object using date range. I did below query

```
Person.update({'data.date': {'$gte': '1-1-2016', '$lte': '1-5-2016'}}, 
    {'$set': {'data.$.score':1000}}, 
    {multi:true})
```

Turned out the `score` on date `1-1-2016` only been updated, something is wrong with the $lte?

This is my schema

```
var Person = new Schema({
    name: String,
    data: [{
        date: Date,
        score: Number
    }]
});
```

Comment: `$lte` doesn't look wrong. Could you add your data as well?

Comment: @AntonioVal `[{
    "name": "something",
    "data": [{
      "date": new Date("1-1-2016"),
      "scores": 3,
    }, {
      "date": new Date("1-2-2016"),
      "scores": 3,
    }]`

Comment: Look at the year in the second one :P

Answer (score 0):

I just realized it's because of the positional operator `$`. According to the MongoDB docs:

> Remember that the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first match of the update query document.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

In your case only the first embedded document is being updated because that is the behaviour of the positional operator.

You could use these answers as a reference:

[Multiple use of the positional `$` operator to update nested arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855246/multiple-use-of-the-positional-operator-to-update-nested-arrays)

[Multiple update of embedded documents' properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8505489/multiple-update-of-embedded-documents-properties)

Comment: what? what is the answer for this question? what is the problem? please be specified.

Comment: I just expanded the explanation, because of the behaviour of the positional operator only your first embedded document is being updated.

Comment: so any solution for this? means I can't update mutliple docs using gte and lte?? Hmm I expect multi:true is used for that.

Comment: `multi: true` is used through multiple documents, not through embedded documents inside the same document (it does not have any effect). It seems there is not a direct solution for these cases, take a look to the answers I posted.

Comment: I think I have to look and execute my above query.